# PHP $conn->closed() Doesn't Remove Process In PROCESSLIST table

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, amazon-rds

I have `AWS RDS - MariaDB 10.1.31, db.t2.medium`. and I always use this code to connect and close into RDS instance :

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//--- SOME CODES HERE

$conn->close();
```

I run my codes using cron every minute. Then I checked the process using this command :

```
mysql> SELECT IP_ADDRESS, COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM ( SELECT SUBSTRING(HOST, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(HOST) - 6) AS IP_ADDRESS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST  GROUP BY HOST ) AS t1 GROUP BY IP_ADDRESS ORDER BY IP_ADDRESS DESC;
+--------------+-----+
| IP_ADDRESS   | NUM |
+--------------+-----+
| localhost    |   1 |
| 172.31.9.xxx |   4 |
| 172.31.3.yy  |  10 |
| 172.31.2.zzz |   1 |
+--------------+-----+
4 rows in set (0.34 sec)
```

I run that command every second and realise that IP address from one of EC2 instance still there even I put `$conn->close();` in my codes.

it seems that the process stuck in the PROCESSLIST table.

how to immediately have PROCESSLIST table clear after `$conn->close();` executed?

thank you.

Comment: **Note:** _from the manual_ `mysqli_close()` will not close persistent connections. For additional details, see the manual page on [persistent connections.](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php)

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB/RDS are you using?  There are persistent connections below the PHP level, too.